# fastboot flash recovery doesn't work on HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire, fastboot, recovery-mode

I'm trying to update ClockworkMod recovery on HTC Desire.

Fastboot recognizes the device:

```
$fastboot devices
HT03PPL04520    fastboot
```

But flash recovery fails:

```
$fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
sending 'recovery' (3054 KB)...
FAILED (status malformed (1 bytes))
finished. total time: 0.002s
```

P.S. The reason why I want to update the recovery is that when I try to install zip from sd card I get something like this: "error can't open /sdcard/update.zip (bad)"

Comment: Have you verified the [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) of the recovery.img file (one is typically provided)? The error seems to indicate that it's corrupt, or not actually a recovery image.

Comment: Checksum was not povided but I tried to download it twice.

Comment: Well, if flashing your device fails and you also can't run things from the SD card that you have no reason believing should be corrupt, maybe you have some kind of hardware malfunction in your phone. Can you try another USB cable/port?

Answer (score 0):

Download a [clockworkmod recovery](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-touch-5.8.0.2-bravo.img) from offsite and firstly try to use fastboot boot. If it works correctly, flash recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Try fastboot flash --RECOVERY recovery.img --no-reboot

Answer (score 0):

As Penguinolog said, try to "fastboot boot" into the recovery using "fastboot boot recovery.img".

If you can,the recovery is not to blame. Rather, the recovery partition may have accumulated some bad blocks which might have to be cleared beforehand flashing the recovery.